# Internal server error with asp.net and angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have the following model in my javascript

```
$scope.newQuestionnaireForm = {
    QuestionnaireName: '',
    QuestionnaireCategory: '',
    QuestionnaireIntro: '',
    Duration: 2,
    Period: 'Weeks',
    StartDate: new Date($filter('date')(currentDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")),
    EndDate: '',
    Questions: [{ QuestionIndex: 1, QuestionDescription: '', QuestionType: 'TextBox', Choices: [{ ChoiceText: '' }] }]
};
```

And my c# model looks like this

```
public class NewQuestionnaireViewModel
{

    public string QuestionnaireName { get; set; }

    public string QuestionnaireCategory { get; set; }

    public string QuestionnaireIntro { get; set; }

    public string StartDate { get; set; }

    public string EndDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsDraft { get; set; }

    public QuestionViewModel[] Questions { get; set; }

}

public class QuestionViewModel
{

    public QuestionViewModel(int QuestionIndex, string QuestionDescription, string QuestionType, ChoiceViewModel[] Choices)
    {
        this.QuestionIndex = QuestionIndex;
        this.QuestionDescription = QuestionDescription;
        this.QuestionType = QuestionType;
        this.Choices = Choices;
    }
    public int QuestionIndex { get; set; }

    public string QuestionDescription { get; set; }

    public string QuestionType { get; set; }

    public ChoiceViewModel[] Choices { get; set; }

}

public class ChoiceViewModel
{

    public ChoiceViewModel(string ChoiceText)
    {
        this.ChoiceText = ChoiceText;
    }

    public string ChoiceText { get; set; }
}
```

And I post it to the server with the following javascript model

```
QuestionnaireName: model.QuestionnaireName,
            QuestionnaireCategory: model.QuestionnaireCategory,
            QuestionnaireIntro: model.QuestionnaireIntro,
            StartDate: model.StartDate,
            EndDate: model.EndDate,
            IsDraft: isDraft,
            Questions: model.Questions
```

Now when I try to add a new questionnaire, it gives me a Internal Server error 500 error. Any ideas on why this is happening? I suspect a model binding error because it doesnt even reach my controller code.

Comment: No execption is thrown, the only error I get is in the chrome console saying Internal Server error.

Comment: Could you check the Networks tab in the dev tools and see if the request has any response body included? There might be more information as to why the request failed. If you suspect it might be cause by model binding, including that part of your controller would be helpful as well.

Comment: At the moment I cant run the application because my visual studio is broken saying I need directx even though it is installed and when I try to run the directx setup it says that I need to be a admin even though I am an admin account and have launched it with admin privileges.